# saving multiple files with cURL

Tags: bash, curl

I have this list of URLs in a .txt file -which i'm suppose to get content of them. To achieve this, i decided to use cURL. With **xargs curl < url-list.txt** , i can display all the content of the URL within my terminal. With **curl -o myFile.html www.example.com** , i can save only 1 file.

There is also **curl -O URL1 -O URL2** approach but it will be too long for me to do it.

How can i save multiple files **at once**?

**Edit:**

```
#!/bin/bash
file="filename"

while read line
do 
  curl -o "$line.html" "$line"
done < "$file"
```

i run the bash screen above and here is what happened:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build up a bash script to loop through your list of URLs and perform the curl command.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="filename"

while read line
do 
  outfile=$(echo $line | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/" } ; {print $NF}')
  curl -o "$outfile.html" "$line"
done < "$file"
```

Comment: I run your script but it fails. I updated question for you with a screenshot

Comment: Ok the problem is with the filename. It has all those weird characters from the URL, I thought quotes might take care of that. Check my edit. That `awk` command will give you just the last part of the url as your file name.

Comment: This solves my problem perfectly. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

While the simplest approach is to create a loop script as suggested by @dan08, if the links you need to download are consecutive, for example:

```
http://www.host.com/page-1.html
http://www.host.com/page-2.html
```

and so on, you can use the curl command like this:

```
curl "http://www.host.com/page-[1-30].html" -o "# 1.html" #(30 is indicative)
```

this will create the files consecutively, using the value of the current range in place of #1 in the filename.

Comment: I'm afraid links are not consecutive. For instance, http://www.ots.at/presseaussendung/OTS_20130402_OTS0038/bayr-begruesst-urteil-im-patentstreit-gegen-novartis-groessere-ueberlebenschancen-fuer-millionen-menschen-durch-leistbare-medikamente